# SSH access a remote client through a tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

I'm a newbie with everything network related and i want to access a remote client through another server (tunnel), 
say for example a remote client 11.11.111.111 with username user2 and password2 , and a tunnel through 11.11.10.01 with username user1 and password1

I can ping successfully the adress tunnel address. 
but when i try to access the remote client using cygwin :

```
ssh -vv -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -vv user1@11.11.10.01 nc %h %p' user2@11.11.111.111
```

I get this error :

```
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -vv user1@11.11.10.01 nc 11.11.111.111 22
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 146765
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 11.11.10.01 [11.11.10.01] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 11.11.10.01 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 11.11.10.01 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is my command correct, any ideas on possible causes ?

are there ways i can troubleshoot (preferbly on my machine and not on server and remote client) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just a partial answer but try connecting with ssh to 11.11.10.01 with:

`ssh user1@11.11.10.01 -L20022:11.11.111.111:22`

and then in another window connect via:

`ssh user2@127.0.0.1 -p20022`

In such way you will get the error in the first terminal window.

Comment: Do you have nc installed on 11.11.10.01?